# ASP.NET MVC3 IAuthorisationfilter Ninject Dependency

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

Currently I am trying to set up dependency injection and override the authorisation attribute. I have tried to follow a few examples although I always seem to get errors.

Global.asax

```
public class MvcApplication : Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectHttpApplication
{
    private class MyModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            this.BindFilter<SageAdminAuthorizationFilter>(FilterScope.Controller, 0);
            Bind<IAuthentication>().To<CustomAuthenticationService>();
        }
    }

    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }

    protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var modules = new INinjectModule[] {
        new MyModule()
    };
        var kernel = new StandardKernel(modules);

        return kernel;
    }
}
```

Authentication Filter

```
public class CustomAuthenticationService : IAuthentication
{
    public void SignIn(string claimedIdentifier, bool createPersistentCookie)
    {
        //Write Sign in code here
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(claimedIdentifier, createPersistentCookie);
    }

    public void SignOut()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    }

    public bool Authorize(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        //Check here if the user can administer the  admin
        return false;
    }
}

//The Authorization attribute on a controller
public class CustomAdminAuthorizationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly IAuthentication _authentication;

    public SageAdminAuthorizationFilter(IAuthentication authentication)
    {
        _authentication = authentication;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        _authentication.Authorize(filterContext.HttpContext);
    }
}
```

I always receive

> Sequence contains no elements.

Any help would appreciated.

Update:
I am still receiving the same error.

The call stack is as follows

Locating source for 'c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject.web.mvc\mvc3\src\Ninject.Web.Mvc\NinjectHttpApplication.cs'. Checksum: MD5 {3d e3 7f 86 44 70 db 0 3c 6f e0 97 fb 1e 12 13}
The file 'c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject.web.mvc\mvc3\src\Ninject.Web.Mvc\NinjectHttpApplication.cs' does not exist.
Looking in script documents for 'c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject.web.mvc\mvc3\src\Ninject.Web.Mvc\NinjectHttpApplication.cs'...
Looking in the projects for 'c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject.web.mvc\mvc3\src\Ninject.Web.Mvc\NinjectHttpApplication.cs'.
The file was not found in a project.
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\'...
The debug source files settings for the active solution indicate that the debugger will not ask the user to find the file: c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject.web.mvc\mvc3\src\Ninject.Web.Mvc\NinjectHttpApplication.cs.
The debugger could not locate the source file 'c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject.web.mvc\mvc3\src\Ninject.Web.Mvc\NinjectHttpApplication.cs'.

I have installed Ninject and Ninject.MVC3 from Nuget. It looks although it is trying to find the files to debug. Would anyone be able to give me any information to why this is happening.

I also receive this error

[InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements]
   System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(IEnumerable`1 source) +320
   Ninject.Web.Mvc.Bootstrapper.Initialize(Func`1 createKernelCallback) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject.web.mvc\mvc3\src\Ninject.Web.Mvc\Bootstrapper.cs:67
   Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectHttpApplication.Application_Start() in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject.web.mvc\mvc3\src\Ninject.Web.Mvc\NinjectHttpApplication.cs:65

Comment: Sorry the dependecy resolver is a red herring. It was left from trying to follow other peoples examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Action filters should be registered using the following syntax:

```
public override void Load()
{
    BindFilter<CustomAdminAuthorizationFilter>(FilterScope.Controller, 0);
    Bind<IAuthentication>().To<CustomAuthenticationService>();
}
```

You can also [apply the filter conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479066/bind-a-global-action-filter-to-all-controllers-in-an-area-using-mvc-3-dependency/5479132#5479132).

Remark: can't see any relation with the `NinjectDependencyResolver` class you are showing in your question. That's already built into ninject.mvc3 and you shouldn't be writing it manually.

Comment: Hi Darin, Thank you very much it looks like it should work although I am receiving the same error. I will do some testing, the call stack is trying to look for the ninject source code. I will carry on investigating and confirm whether this resolved my issue.

Answer (score -1):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsdebug/thread/933f62dd-80e5-4ef3-9199-9e9abfefeadf

resolved by un-checking the box next to “Require source files to exactly match the original version” in

```
Tools --> Options --> Debugging --> General
```

No fruitcup for scientologists