# Authorisation exceptions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, authorize

I've tagged my controller with an authority annotation but would like to exempt one of the methods... can that be done? how?

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    [DEAUTHORIZE]
    public ActionResult Start(int it)
    { ... }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this can't be done. The standard way to achieve this is to simply move the `Start` action out in a separate controller. Another possibility consists into building a custom [IFilterProvider](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/service-location-pt4-filters.html) which will apply the authorization attribute conditionally instead of baking it manually into the `ProductController`. For example NInject uses this and provides a [pretty fluent syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439921/mvc-3-dependency-injection-with-ninject-2-2-global-action-filter/5442287#5442287) into configuring action filters. You can [conditionally apply them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479066/bind-a-global-action-filter-to-all-controllers-in-an-area-using-mvc-3-dependency/5479132#5479132) based on the current context.

Comment: thanks for the straight answer.  Will look into NInject... looks interesting.

Answer (score 4):

In MVC 4 was introduced AllowAnonymousAttribute which tells action invoker to skip AuthorizeAttribute.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
```